# Mysql NOT IS NULL behavior

Tags: mysql, null, sql-execution-plan, notnull

Why does **NOT NULL** condition forces Mysql to check whole table, instead looking only in subquery result?

[image: mysql-is-null]

[image: mysql-not-is-null]

Why EXPLAIN the same in this query and in previous, where I try to filter after some subquery ?

[image]

Comment: You should not post images of your code, you should refer to this [ask]

Comment: There is not only code, than EXPLAIN command result, it is looking better when used as image, ive tried do this as CODE, but the question looking like a mess, sorry for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to `NOT NULL`. The query planner believes that to be more efficient. 
When more that 50% of the rows match it is often faster to skip using an index. 
You can `ANALYZE TABLE` to make sure the planner has the latest information, or `FORCE INDEX` should you believe to know better.

Is this query just to support the question or actually in use? It's not ideal to create a temporary table `sub` and filtering it after.

Comment: The real query is more complicated, and it solws as hell if I add NOT IS NULL condition. So ive tried to make it as subquery and after filter by NOT NULL, but it doesnt work, Mysql EXPLAIN shows that theres no difference if I add NOT NULL to subquery or to parent query, and I cant get why.

Comment: Updated, with screeshot